# Glsl shader not set to an instance

Tags: c#, glsl

Hello can anyone help me with this line of codes? ive been facing this object not set to an instance error and i was given this method to try by someone from stackoverflow too. Thanks so much!

```
string shader = @"#version 120
#version 150 compatibility

uniform sampler2D tex;

void main()
{       
     vec4 pixcol = texture2D(tex, gl_TexCoord[0].xy);
     vec4 colors[3];
     colors[0] = vec4(0.,0.,1.,1.);
     colors[1] = vec4(1.,1.,0.,1.);
     colors[2] = vec4(1.,0.,0.,1.);
     float lum = (pixcol.r+pixcol.g+pixcol.b)/3.;
     int ix = (lum < 0.5)? 0:1;
     vec4 thermal = mix(colors[ix],colors[ix+1],(lum-float(ix)*0.5)/0.5);
     gl_FragColor = thermal;
}";

GL.ShaderSource(m_shader_handle, shader);
```

Answer (score 1):

https://www.opengl.org/wiki/Core_Language_(GLSL)#Version

> The #version​ directive must appear before anything else in a shader, save for whitespace and comments. If a #version​ directive does not appear at the top, then it assumes 1.10, which is almost certainly not what you want.

use one version **120** or **150**

**try:**

```
string shader = @"#version 150 compatibility // or 120 if you want

uniform sampler2D tex;
```